# JPA2: How to map only certain table rows to an entity?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

I have a table I cannot change with approximately this structure

```
ID, name, purpose, rubbish...
1, foo, PRICING, ...
2, bar, INVENTORY, ...
3, bar, PRICING, ...
```

What is the preferred way to map only the lines with purpose=PRICING to an Entity? Is there a way to do this with JPA annotations or do I need a view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy, and use "purpose" as discriminator column like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="THE_TABLE")
@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="purpose", discriminatorType=STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("PRICING")
public class Pricing{ ... }
```

Comment: +1 for the idea, but wouldn't that only work with a @MappedSuperclass parent?

Comment: It should just work. I took the code example from DiscriminatorValue API javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorValue.html

Comment: Thank you, that looks exactly like the thing I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe pure JPA supports this.

If you're using Hibernate, you can use filters. Nice examples can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/).

This is one example when using vendor specific extensions are real nice, but they lock you to one implementation. It's possible other implementations (OpenJPA, EclipseLink...) also support this, but I haven't looked at them yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to only select rows where purpose=Pricing.

There are to basic steps: (1) create an entity, (2) create a query. 
The entity would use annotations and be similar to this :

```
 @Entity 
 public class Foo
  { 
    String name;
    String inventory; 
    ....
  }
```

Then you simply construct and execute a query :

```
.....
    @PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

 .....
 public List<Foo> getAllWithPricing()
 {
     return entityManager.createQuery("select o from Foo o where o.purpose='PRICING'", Foo.class).getResultList()

 }
```

Comment: I know how to **select** certain entities, but in this case I want to avoid to create any "non-pricing" entities at all. If someone would accidentally create one of these, they could wreak havok in the system.